# Cordova 5.3.3 in Windows 10 input field doesn't show On-Screen-Keyboard automatically

Tags: cordova, windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

We developed a very simple application with just one input field in a div. Running the application on a web browser bring the OSK automatically, as expected. Once we compiled the application using Cordova 5.3.3 as a Windows Universal mode for Windows 10, the application is not showing the OSK. Also, the swipe event is not working. All other touch events are working. In reality we have a much more complex j-script application but we are experimenting the same issues, in the browser it works OK.

Is there any configuration we are missing in the Cordova project to fix this issue?

Comment: Interesting enough, when using a pen, the swipe and the on-screen-keyboard are working perfect and consistently, in many different devices, all using windows 10. The same application, compiled in windows 8.1 using Cordova 5.1.0 works OK regarding the swipe and the OSK, with some other issues related with compatibility with the CSS and some other sensitivity and performance issues not present in the windows 10 application.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?